# Kill process via sh script called by crontab

Tags: bash, shell, cron

i wrote a **sh** file which kills a tomcat process, suppose my shell scrip is in **/usr/temp**, script looks likethat:

```
#!/bin/bash
ps -Af | grep "tomcat_something" | grep -v grep | awk '{print$2}' | xargs sudo kill -9
```

then i created a cron via `crontab -e` My cron looks likethat (dont pay attention to the time):

```
10 10 * * * /usr/temp/myshellscript.sh
```

If i run the **sh** without cron it works fine, but via cron is not working at all. 
I even tryied to run the same shell script with a **touch file command** and in this case cron works fine, so my doubt is that the problem is the **kill** command. Can someone help ?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/tags/cron/info

Comment: If there was an error in the cronjob you should get an email. If you don't have email configured on the system try running `mailx` to read local mail. BTW - could you use `killall -s 9 "tomcat_something"` instead?

Comment: Finally i found the solution to my problem my self, when i realized it i felt a bit stupid :D . First of all, the code i wrote and the procedure i followed its totally right so if someone is intrested can follow it. The problem was that, in the test phase I was modifying the regular expression via 'crontab -e' , so that it was performed 1-2 minutes later, I think this did not give the operating system the time necessary to install the cronjob

Answer (score 0):

**Problem:**

`sudo` in `cron` job does not work as it expects a password to be entered.

**Possible Solutions**

Not Recommended as require to give password in plaintext.

> Use `expect` (Quick google or SO search will help you) in your script
>   and provide sudo's password there.

Run your script as `sudo` instead of running `sudo` inside script

In your own crontab, write your command like so:

```
10 10 * * * echo "your password" | sudo -S /usr/temp/myshellscript.sh
```

Again, **it is not recommended**

**Best Possible Way: Use roots crontab (only if you have access)**

Run the following command:

```
sudo crontab -e
```

This opens up root's crontab. sudo is not necessary to run your command in this context since it'll be invoked as root anyway.

Comment: Thank you @Avinash for your effort. i wrote a comment  to my question which solved my problem!